# Error "This site cant be reached" in web page while using php

Tags: php

```
my php code:
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
            <?php
            echo "this is ";
            echo "title";
            ?>
        </title> </head> <body>
         </body> </html>
```

I am getting "This site cant be reached in my chrome browser when i am writing "localhost/phpTutorial/comments.php" , here php tutorial is the folder where all php files are storing and phh tutorial is made inside htdocs of XAMPP folder and i am unable to run m y files

location description:- c:->XAMPP->htdocs->phpTutorial->comments.php AND  i am writing "localhost/phpTutorial/comment.php" in my chrome browser and then it is saying this site cant be reached

please solve my issue and suggest what is wrong in this in a beginner friendly way

Comment: Make sure xampp server is started

Comment: Go To Your Xampp Folder, Click on xamppcontrol.exe and then click the start buttons near `Apache` & `MySQL`

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access "localhost/phpTutorial/comment.php" but you said you have c:->XAMPP->htdocs->phpTutorial->comments.php.... try this **"localhost/phpTutorial/comments.php"** and make sure your localhost is running !!!!

Comment: yes i mean same i.e, comment is right but nothing is working here , nor localhost/phpTutorial is working not any thing is working . one day ago all was good and was running properly but vs code asked for some setting and i have accidentally clicked on it so may be that should be reason . please do something for this

Comment: i really dont think VScode has anything to do.... unless there is any change in  settings made regarding localhost....how about sharing screen shot of the error....i wonder if there is more than "This site can not be reached".  This is longshot.... but did you try ending all the processes of xampp controller  and apache ..and restarting it again.....Basically complete restart of the server......

Comment: i cant do that because i doesnt have required reputation, the error is "This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: did you try restarting the 1. apache server 2. xampp controller 3. YOUR PC. sometime everything you need is just restart...i hope it helps...do keep posted the results...and make sure first... 127.0.0.1  or/and localhost/phpmyadmin is available from your web browser